# Erro - JSF e PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Erro ao tentar cadastrar usuário, aparece a seguinte mensagem:

```
accordion:dtNasc: '22-02-1990' could not be understood as a date.
```

XHTML:

```
<p:outputLabel class="lt" value="Data de Nascimento:" />
<p:calendar id="dtNasc" value="#{usuarioBean.funcionario.dt_nasc}" locale="pt" yearRange="-99:+39" widgetVar="dtNasc"navigator="true" showButtonPanel="true">
<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</p:calendar>
```

Classe Funcionario

```
@NotEmpty(message = "O campo data de nascimento é obrigatório.")
@Column(name = "fun_dt_nasc", nullable = false)
private String dt_nasc;


public String getDt_nasc() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(getDt_nasc());
}
public void setDt_nasc(String dt_nasc) {
    setDt_nasc(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(dt_nasc));
}
```

No meu get ele dá um erro:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Date to String

Comment: Qual é o tipo do atributo dt_nasc na classe funcionario?

Comment: Ele é String...
private String dt_nasc;

Comment: Calendar precisa que o atributo seja do tipo Date

Answer (score 2):

Como vc disse, seu atributo dt_nasc é do tipo String e o Calendar precisa que seja do tipo Date.

Ou você troca isso ou cria um método para converter, por exemplo:

```
public Date getDtNasc(){
    return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(getDt_nasc());
}
public void setDtNasc(Date data){
    setDt_nasc(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(data));
}
```

E no seu xhtml:

```
<p:calendar id="dtNasc" value="#{usuarioBean.funcionario.dtNasc}" locale="pt" yearRange="-99:+39" widgetVar="dtNasc"navigator="true" showButtonPanel="true">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</p:calendar>
```

Comment: Nilson, não conseguir cadastrar mudando o atribuito para Date, e quando coloco igual vc fez no get e set dá erro... Vou postar no código acima....